# Synchronizing data from AWS Sql Server to local database

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication, aws, amazon-ec2

I have a situation when I need to synchronize some tables from `Sql Server` database to my local `Sql Server` database and vice versa. What are my options? I can not find any useful information about replications. Some says it is not supported on `AWS`. May be mirroring or any other way?

Answer (score 2):

The basic options for replication in SQL Server are available between AWS and on-premise...as long as you have the network access in place.

I'm not sure what source you used to find it was not supported. AWS also offers the Database Migration Service which supports multiple RDBMS and various targets. You can find more information on that [here](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/).

Comment: Hello @Shawn, so if I configure connections between AWS and local machine I will be able to do replications between instances on AWS and local? We have SQL Server Express editions on both. I sthere any walkthrough articles about this? If row is added to a table on AWS it shoud be replicated to local and vice versa.

Comment: You follow normal documentation for configuring replication in SQL Server. With regards to AWS, you will need to check that documentation for exact steps. You simply need to ensure the network access (ports, etc.) or open between your EC2 instance and on-premise machine.

Comment: it is not supported by RDS if that's what you use.

Comment: What is not supported by RDS? Replicating data into or out of RDS for SQL Server is most certainly supported.